# How to select single element value which created dynamically in html using jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario like this:

```
for (var k in active) {
        notifications.append(
            '<a href="javascript:toast();">' +
            '<div>' +
            '<input class="phone_number" type="hidden" id='+active[k].phone_number+' value='+active[k].phone_number+'>'+
            '</input>'+
            '<span class="notify bg-blue">' + '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' + '</span>' +
            '<span>' +
            '<span>Sim ' + active[k].phone_number + ' Expires in ' + active[k].expiry_count + 'days</span>' +
            '<br/>' +
            '<span class="time">Just Now</span>' +
            '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</input>'+
            '</a>');
    }
```

i created dynamic elements using jade template engine. 
here i need to identify each `<a>` click and i nedd to get the value of hidden field.

```
function toast() {
    var grade;
    //var phone_number=document.getElementById('phone_number').value;
    $.each($('.phone_number'), function () {
                    grade = $(this).val();
        alert(grade);
    });
}
```

by doing this i got a loop of value. which i didn't want. i need single item value. how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
notifications = $(".notifications")

active = [{ phone_number: "982334",expiry_count: "1"},
         { phone_number: "982334",expiry_count: "1"}]
var k;
for (var k in active) {
         
        notifications.append(
            '<a href="javascript:toast();">' +
            '<div>' +
            '<input class="phone_number" type="hidden" id='+active[k].phone_number+' value='+active[k].phone_number+'>'+
            '</input>'+
            '<span class="notify bg-blue">' + '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' + '</span>' +
            '<span>' +
            '<span>Sim ' + active[k].phone_number + ' Expires in ' + active[k].expiry_count + 'days</span>' +
            '<br/>' +
            '<span class="time">Just Now</span>' +
            '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</input>'+
            '</a>');
    }
    
    
      $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
         
          alert($(this).find('.phone_number').val())
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="notifications"></div>
```

**Its simple.Try this**

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
          alert($(this).find('.phone_number').val())
    })
```

Comment: @AnonymousObject try this

Comment: bro its working but, it invoking multiple times and some times i got undefined value.

Comment: @AnonymousObject  try now. I given sample snippet as well.

Comment: @AnonymousObject I hope you got the solution. If you found it useful please upvote and accept answer.Thank YOU

Comment: bro i am using jade template, i dont know what the error is, i still got multiple  alert messages on single click .

Comment: Ohh sorry bro.. i just put that code in a function `'<a href="javascript:toast();">'` thats why i got that error, after putting it on `document.ready()` its ok now! :) thaks mate

Comment: i created the href class to `n_href` and wrote this `$(document).on('click', '.n_href', function () {
            alert($(this).find('.phone_number').val())
        })` now it working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

pass `this` to the toast

```
 '<a href="javascript:toast(this);">' +
```

and change the `toast` method to

```
function toast( thisObj ) 
{
    var grade = $( thisObj ).parent().find( '.phone_number[type="hidden"]' ).attr( "value" );
    alert( grade );
}
```

Comment: can you put a `console` log statement in the `toast` and tell me what is the `grade` value?

Comment: bro the `toast` function not invoking.

Comment: was it invoking earlier? Can you create a snippet so that current issue can be replicated and verified?

Comment: bro now its invoked, but got no value. i got `undefined` (i am using jade templating engine),

Comment: I don't think Jade has a role to play once if you are appending markup to an element this way. Using @krishnar's code, can you replicate the issue you are facing?

Comment: yes bro, but on that code i ran on to another issue when i click on any `<a>` the it invoked!! :P

Answer (score 0):

Send the toast function the k you are iterating over

`'<a href="javascript:toast(' + k + ');">'`

then use k in your function

```
function toast(k) {
   //use k (maybe select by id)
}
```